# Numpy indexing: Set values of an array given by conditions in different array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I want to set all values of an array to 0 that have values that are not in a different array.

Easy if it's only one condition:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[5,6]])
cond = 1
a[a!=cond] = 0
```

What about if I have a list of conditions, e.g.

```
cond = np.array([1,2,6])
```

I can write it out like this

```
a[(a!=1) & (a!=2) & (a!=6)]=0
```

but I can't figure out the general way of doing this, something like this

```
a[a!=cond] = 0
```

when `cond` is an array. I also looked at `np.select` but that doesn't seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crux of the solution is :

`NOT( option1) & NOT(option2) & NOT(option3)` would be an equivalent of

`NOT (option1 | option2 | option3 )`.

Now, to get the mask for `option1 | option2 | option3`, we have a built-in [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html). So, basically the solution would be somewhat like `~np.in1d(a,cond)`. Since `np.in1d` works on 1D array, we need to reshape it afterwards before using the mask on the input array for setting values as zeros.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
a[~np.in1d(a,cond).reshape(a.shape)] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's the function `np.in1d` which tests if the first array
contains any of the items from the second array. 
But since this works on 1d arrays, and you need to test on a 2d array
the solution is a bit tricky, using the fact that `ravel()` returns a view:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[5,6]])
a.ravel()[~np.in1d(a.ravel(), [1, 2, 6])] = 0
print(a)
```

And then you get the output:

```
[[1 2]
 [2 0]
 [0 6]]
```